# Service with background jobs, how to ensure jobs only run periodically ONCE per cluster

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, couchdb, jobs

I have a play framework based service that is stateless and intended to be deployed across many machines for horizontal scaling.

This service is handling HTTP JSON requests and responses, and is using CouchDB as its data store again for maximum scalability.

We have a small number of background jobs that need to be run every X seconds across the whole cluster. It is vital that the jobs do not execute concurrently on each machine.

To execute the jobs we're using Actors and the Akka Scheduler (since we're using Scala):

```
Akka.system().scheduler.schedule(
    Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
        Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
        Akka.system().actorOf(LoggingJob.props),
        "tick")
```

(etc)

```
object LoggingJob {
    def props = Props[LoggingJob]
}

class LoggingJob extends UntypedActor {
    override def onReceive(message: Any) {
        Logger.info("Job executed! " + message.toString())
    }
}
```

Is there:

- any built in trickery in Akka/Actors/Play that I've missed that will do this for me?
- OR a recognised algorithm that I can put on top of Couchbase (distributed mutex? not quite?) to do this?

I do not want to make any of the instances 'special' as it needs to be very simple to deploy and manage.

Comment: I have the same issue as yours. I have a play application which has a akka scheduler which runs every12 hours and does certain DB operation. But I want it run once in a cluster. Otherwise if I have 2 node cluster then 4 times it will run I want it to be only twice a day. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Akka's [Cluster Singleton Pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/contrib/cluster-singleton.html).

> For some use cases it is convenient and sometimes also mandatory to
>   ensure that you have exactly one actor of a certain type running
>   somewhere in the cluster.
>
> Some examples:
>
> - single point of responsibility for certain cluster-wide consistent decisions, or coordination of actions across the cluster system
> - single entry point to an external system
> - single master, many workers
> - centralized naming service, or routing logic
>
> Using a singleton should not be the first design choice. It has
>   several drawbacks, such as single-point of bottleneck. Single-point of
>   failure is also a relevant concern, but for some cases this feature
>   takes care of that by making sure that another singleton instance will
>   eventually be started.

Comment: That looks pretty good, my only reservation is that it makes use of a gossip protocol to get eventual consistency when we've got a nice data store sitting there to be used for synchronization! I've scanned the docs and can't find any info on pulling the gossip protocol out for something else - do you know if that is worth the time or not?

Comment: I doubt that it's feasible.  The gossip protocol is a core part of Akka Cluster.

Comment: I have the same issue as yours. I have a play application which has a akka scheduler which runs and does certain DB operation. But I want it run once in a cluster. How can we achieve this?